# Independent/independently of/from

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of these are correct, and why? Suggestions for rephrasing it are also welcome.

> [noun] was developed independently of [noun]
>
> [noun] was developed independently from [noun]
>
> [noun] was developed, independent of [noun]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

*Independently of* is correct here.  To be independent *of* something means to not depend on it for anything essential.  Hence, the following is the best choice:

> [Noun] was developed independently of [noun].

*Independently from* is not correct usage, as well as being [very uncommon](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=independently%20of,independently%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  *From* X would indicate either *coming* from X or *going away* from X, neither of which applies here, since independence does not come or go *from* something.

The third option, though decipherable, does not mean exactly the same thing since *independent* could just as easily be referring to the [noun] as to the development, creating an ambiguity, as well as an unnecessary comma.  Both of these should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Looking at your Google Ngram results, *independently from* is even rarer than the results indicate, since many of them are of forms similar to *The two ships will proceed independently from Miami to ...*

Comment: [Here](http://www.beatthegmat.com/idiom-independently-of-vs-independently-from-t9029.html) someone claims that "*independent from is used for the independence of entities such as people or nations*", and gives an example: "*he has been independent from his parents since he [...]*". Do you think that is also a correct perspective?

Comment: @KajMagnus While my soap box is not large enough for me to feel comfortable calling his perspective "incorrect", I think that *he has been independent of his parents* works just fine and is in fact [more popular](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=independent+of+his+parents%2Cindependent+from+his+parents&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than his option.  I simply do not see his distinction played out in everyday usage.

Comment: Yes, but looking at the Google Ngram and extrapolating into the future, 'independently from' should be just as common by 2200. ;)

Comment: Is it the same when talking about software dependencies?